# Returning an array of values from timestamps between a start and end time

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have a query that produces a timestamp and a value at that timestamp.

```
select timestamp, value
from table1;
```

So, a sample from the data would look like this:

```
      timestamp      |     value      |
---------------------------------------
 2019-02-28 01:00:00 | 1              |
 2019-02-28 01:10:00 | 1              |
 2019-02-28 01:20:00 | 6              |
 2019-02-28 01:30:00 | 17             |
 2019-02-28 01:40:00 | 4              |
 2019-02-28 01:50:00 | 4              |
```

I have a second query that produces a start timestamp and an end timestamp.

```
select start, end
from table2;
```

A sample from that would look like this:

```
       start        |         end         |
-------------------------------------------
2019-02-28 01:00:00 | 2019-02-28 01:30:00 |
2019-02-28 01:40:00 | 2019-02-28 01:50:00 |
```

How would I be able to combine the two queries to produce an output like this?

```
       start        |         end         |      values     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
2019-02-28 01:00:00 | 2019-02-28 01:30:00 | {1,1,6}         |
2019-02-28 01:40:00 | 2019-02-28 01:50:00 | {4}             |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation and `join`:

```
select t2.start, t2.end, array_agg(t1.value)
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.timestamp >= t2.start and t1.timestamp < t2.end
group by t2.start, t2.end;
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if this would also work with two temporary tables?

Comment: @hov . . . Temporary tables have nothing to do with the logic.  This will work on temporary tables, permanent tables, views, CTEs, and subqueries.